# ¿Método de encriptación en común con Java, Android (con java) y PHP?

Tags: java, php, android, encriptación

Me veo en la necesidad de realizar encriptación de datos, el punto es que necesito un método de encriptación y desencriptar (o solo encriptación incluso) en común con Java SE, PHP y Android con Java también, por el momento no he encontrado mucha información, solo entre Java SE y Android, pero PHP no, tengo la idea de crear mi propio método de encriptación usando arrays ciclos y condicionales, pero antes de ello quisiera que alguien me dijera si existe un método en común entre los lenguajes que ya mencione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos de cifrado y digestión de cadenas de texto que encuentras en los diferentes lenguajes son un standard y son compatibles entre si.

Recomiendo usar las librerías `OpenSSL` con el algoritmo `AES-256-CBC`. Para PHP la documentación está [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-encrypt.php).

Para Java la implementación es un poco complicada pero podrás encontrar mucha información al respecto en Stack Overflow en inglés; [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508961/java-equivalent-of-an-openssl-aes-cbc-encryption) un ejemplo.